# Installing docker CE on redhat 7

Tags: rhel, yum, docker

I am trying to install dockerce on redhat7 by following the below steps

```
yum update -y

yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

yum install docker-ce -y
```

I have got the below errors

> ---> Package docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:18.09.6-3.el7 will be installed
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-18.09.6-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
>              Requires: libcgroup
>
> Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-18.09.6-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
>              Requires: libseccomp >= 2.3
>
> Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-18.09.6-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
>              Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
>
> Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-18.09.6-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
>              Requires: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit)
>
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You
>   could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: what happens if you do `yumdownloader --resolve docker-ce` ? If you dont have `yumdownloader ` then install with `yum install yum-utils` must be run by root user with full privileges.

Comment: Thanks @RakibFiha , but Unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable=1 the [rhel-7-server-extras-rpms] repository in /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo.

Then you can try again :
yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing up the yum and then installing the docker?

`yum clean all`

`yum install docker-ce`

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply @Srikanth , but unfortunately  it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have certain dependencies that are not resolving.

Please use the below and let me know if the installation goes through.

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras
```