# how to installed the latest docker version without dependencies issues

Tags: yum, docker, rpm, dependencies, container

We prepare the following in order to install docker on rhel 7.5 version

( from the list https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/ ) , and only the latest

```
curl https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm -o docker.rpm
curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch.rpm -o containerselinux.rpm
curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/docker-ce-cli-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm     -o docker-ce-cli.rpm
curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64.rpm        -o containerd.io.rpm
```

and the files are:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root       25697324 May  8 13:17 docker.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root           7793 May  8 13:18 containerselinux.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root           7793 May  8 13:21 docker-ce-cli.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root           7793 May  8 13:24 containerd.io.rpm
```

Not we want to install all them

```
 yum localinstall -y  docker-ce-cli.rpm containerselinux.rpm docker.rpm  containerd.io.rpm
    Loaded plugins: langpacks
configuration
    Cannot open: docker-ce-cli.rpm. Skipping.
    Cannot open: containerselinux.rpm. Skipping.
    Examining docker.rpm: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64
    Marking docker.rpm to be installed
    Cannot open: containerd.io.rpm. Skipping.
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.8-3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: containerd.io >= 1.2.2-3 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: docker-ce-cli for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64 (/docker)
               Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
    Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64 (/docker)
               Requires: docker-ce-cli
    Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64 (/docker)
               Requires: containerd.io >= 1.2.2-3
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

We  not understand why we get 

    Requires: docker-ce-cli
    Requires: containerd.io >= 1.2.2-3
    Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
```

Since we installed the latest versions

second

we get also

```
Cannot open: docker-ce-cli.rpm. Skipping.
Cannot open: containerselinux.rpm. Skipping.
```

but what is wrong with my curl?

after I fixed and set the right URL we still get:

```
yum localinstall  docker.rpm  containerselinux.rpm docker-ce-cli.rpm containerd.io.rpm -y
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Examining docker.rpm: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64
Marking docker.rpm to be installed
Examining containerselinux.rpm: docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch
Marking containerselinux.rpm to be installed
Examining docker-ce-cli.rpm: 1:docker-ce-cli-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64
Marking docker-ce-cli.rpm to be installed
Examining containerd.io.rpm: containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64
Marking containerd.io.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.6-3.3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 4.3 kB  00:00:00
---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.8-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:19.03.8-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package docker-ce-selinux.noarch 0:17.03.3.ce-1.el7 will be installed
Removing docker-ce-selinux.noarch 0:17.03.3.ce-1.el7 - u due to obsoletes from docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.8-3.el7 - u
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.6-3.3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64
---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.8-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package docker-ce-selinux.noarch 0:17.03.3.ce-1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 (/containerd.io)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.8-3.el7.x86_64 (/docker)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: but why , what is wrong with - curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64.rpm        -o containerd.io.rpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`containerselinux.rpm`, `docker-ce-cli.rpm`, and `docker-ce-cli.rpm` aren't actually RPMs, but rather HTML with 404 errors, since you used the wrong URL to download them from. Delete them and re-download them from the right URL.

Comment: what with you mean with thr right URL , I used the right URL , can you please give example ?

Comment: @yael Go to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch.rpm in your browser. It will show you a 404 error.

Comment: thank you so much I fixed it , but still have dependencies issue can you take look ?

Comment: I dont understand why I get this since I use the latest of each rpm's

Comment: @yael https://stackoverflow.com/q/45272827/7509065 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/427665/217726 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/519238/217726

Comment: yes I see the links that you gives actually tell us to download the requested rpm from redhat 7.6 ISO  , but this is what we did we mount -o loop rhel-server-7.X-x86_64-dvd.iso /mnt . and then create the repo , so each rpm that yum needed it can get from the repo , but this isnt happens , do you have idea why? ,

Comment: example from /mnt , ls /mnt
addons  EFI  EULA  extra_files.json  GPL  images  isolinux  LiveOS  media.repo  Packages  repodata  RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta  RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release  TRANS.TBL